# Glass material is looking metallic

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I am using Blender 3.3 on Windows 10 with NVidia graphics.

I wanted to make a transparent glass metarial in cycles which will look real, but whatever I am doing, the transmission is not working.

Is there something I am missing ?

[image]

Comment: Have you chosen Alpha Blend in the Material panel > Settings? Also activate Screen Space Refraction and in the Render panel > Screen Space Reflections and Refraction. If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The total light bounces is still set to 1. Increase that.
Also assuming you are in render view and are using cycles.

If that doesn't help try sharing the file.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Put a Glass BDSF, a Transparent BDSF, plug them both into a Mix Shader

It's that easy.